# Borland C++ crashes without a message

Tags: c++, crash, borland-c++

I'm not sure if anyone uses Borland c++ 3.1, but I have to do it.

I have a program which implements simple threads and changes context of those threads through timer interrupt.

I have an infinite loop and 2 threads that do their job and change between each other and main's thread. Their job is to produce some output, to write something on console.
Problem is that every time I run the program, different thing happens.

Sometimes it works for half a minute and it just stops writing what it should. Write just stops and there is no error and borland doesn't crash.
Sometimes it stops and borland crashes without message.
Sometimes it stops and borland crashes with message "illegal instruction"
Sometimes in the last line it writes before it stops are some weird characters that shouldn't be in output.

Is it the console that is "full" and borland acts weird?
What can be a problem?

Comment: Borland c++ 3.1 was released in 1992... Some SO users were not even born yet, why do you have to use such an old compiler?

Comment: What you describe is indicative of code that isn't thread-safe.  But without seeing any of the crashing code, I can only guess what's wrong with it.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm wrong, but are you trolling?

Comment: @JesseGood Because the teacher told so? Because you can't do easily the same kind of low-level things with better compilers on Windows/Linux/MacOS but still can on DOS either on a bare PC or in an emulator?

Comment: Because I have to make small 16-bit multithreading OS with semaphores and events and for some reason we have to use bcc compiler, teacher's tests are written for that, and I guess he doesnt have time to change the concept of that project and to make it higher-leveled :) Im not trolling

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, is was not safe to write to the console (or use file I/O) under DOS when called from an interrupt. To do it properly, you must check something called "DOS re-entrancy flag" and only write to the console if it is zero (See http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH18/CH18-3.html or search the web for more information)

Comment: Problem was that cout<<something can set I flag in PSW, and to allow interrupts. That is a problem when you use cout<< in an interrupt, cause interrupts must not be allowed in an interrupt function. Its not enough to say something like:  'cout<<something;  asm cli' everytime you use cout<< because interrupt can happen during cout<<something. The solution is to make a flag that will allow changing context only if true, and whenever you want to use cout<< you have to say 'flag = false;  cout<<something; flag = true;' so that even if interrupt happens, it won't do anything since flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

In real and virtual 8086 modes programs aren't protected from each other. So, if your program screws something up, for example:

1. overwrites memory that does not belong to it (or to the appropriate thread in itself), including memory corruptions due to stack overflows in the program or its ISRs
2. fails to preserve (=save, then restore) CPU registers in any of its ISRs
3. changes hardware states to something unexpected to the rest of the system
4. alters timer frequency in obvious to the rest of the system ways

if it does any of that, it should be no surprise that something crashes or hangs or misbehaves in some other way.

I'm guessing that you're having issues 1 and/or 2 above. You can have a race condition there as well.

Unfortunately, without seeing any of your code we can't be of any more help. Think of it, it's like treating a new patient by phone.

Comment: Sorry for code, but it was too long and I wasnt sure where error is, so I had to paste all of it. And I honestly didnt believe anyone would read that :)